# NTFS permissions for a user on another computer in case of a disk moving in a cluster?

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Is there a way to set NTFS permissions for a user on another computer?

I have two nodes in a failover cluster. Both have a specific user account ("charley") local to the node. Charley has files on a disk that is part of a cluster group and in the case of a failover will move to the other node.

Is there a way to configure permissions so that while Node1\Charley creates a file on the disk, Node2\Charley can access (and modify) it after a failover?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions for users unknown to the local system by specifying the SID instead of the user name. You need a tool that accepts SIDs, of course. [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/) does.

It might be simpler to make "charley" a member of one of the predefined local groups like "users" which have a well-known SID (i.e. the same SID on every computer) and set permissions for that group instead of the local user.

Comment: I tried setting the permissions using the SID and icacls and icacls announced that "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.". I tried Powershell set-acl but it doesn't support SIDs.

Comment: Why don't you try SetACL as suggested?

Comment: I found a SetACL which is a third-party tool. I cannot use third-party tools for this project.